JSON Data Processing Created Using Editor.js
I am creating a page that receives JSON data created using Editor.js, a document editor, in the GET method.
{
  "userId": 1,
  "petType": "DOG",
  "title": "Top Tips for Dog Care",
  "category": "TIPS",
  "blocks": [{
      "id": "mhTl6ghSkV",
      "type": "paragraph",
      "data": {
        "text": "Hey. Meet the new Editor. On this picture you can see it in action. Then, try a demo "
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "l98dyx3yjb",
      "type": "header",
      "data": {
        "text": "Key features",
        "level": 3
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "os_YI4eub4",
      "type": "list",
      "data": {
        "type": "unordered",
        "items": [
          "It is a block-style editor",
          "It returns clean data output in JSON",
          "Designed to be extendable and pluggable with a <a href=\"https://editorjs.io/creating-a-block-tool\">simple API</a>"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "TcUNySG15P",
      "type": "paragraph",
      "data": {
        "text": "Workspace in classic editors is made of a single contenteditable element, used to create different HTML markups. Editor.js workspace consists of separate Blocks: paragraphs, headings, images, lists, quotes, etc. Each of them is an independent <sup data-tune=\"footnotes\">1</sup> contenteditable element (or more complex structure) provided by Plugin and united by Editor's Core."
      },
      "tunes": {
        "footnotes": [
          "It works more stable then in other WYSIWYG editors. Same time it has smooth and well-known arrow navigation behavior like classic editors."
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "ksCokKAhQw",
      "type": "paragraph",
      "data": {
        "text": "Classic WYSIWYG editors produce raw HTML-markup with both content data and content appearance. On the contrary, <mark class=\"cdx-marker\">Editor.js outputs JSON object</mark> with data of each Block."
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "XKNT99-qqS",
      "type": "attaches",
      "data": {
        "file": {
          "url": "https://drive.google.com/user/catalog/my-file.pdf",
          "size": 12902,
          "name": "file.pdf",
          "extension": "pdf"
        },
        "title": "My file"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "hZAjSnqYMX",
      "type": "image",
      "data": {
        "file": {
          "url": "assets/codex2x.png"
        },
        "withBorder": false,
        "withBackground": false,
        "stretched": true,
        "caption": "CodeX Code Camp 2019"
      }
    }
  ]
}


However, when I actually received the data, I found that the field was too complex as above api data, and there were so many different factors such as font thickness and italic body application.
Originally, I tried to apply the style myself by separating the elements one by one with a switch case statement, but I thought it was almost impossible.
So my question is, may I know a tool or a way to help you process JSON data made with these editor.js? I couldn't find it however I searched.
I've seen most of the videos involved and I've tried Googling, but I couldn't find a satisfactory answer.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
